# How can I slice a TF dataset so that there's 500 negative examples and 500 positive examples? (IMDB dataset)

Tags: python, tensorflow, dataset, tensorflow-datasets

I have the following dataset:

```
train = tf.keras.preprocessing.text_dataset_from_directory(
    'aclImdb/train', batch_size=64, validation_split=0.2, 
    subset='training', seed=123)
test = tf.keras.preprocessing.text_dataset_from_directory(
    'aclImdb/train', batch_size=64, validation_split=0.2, 
    subset='validation', seed=123)
```

and I am trying to run BERT on this model, however, I only want 1000 examples total of this dataset (500+ve and 500-ve examples), is there a quick and neat way to do this? I am quite new to TF datasets so I'm not sure how I can manipulate them...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you will have dataset of the type `tf.data.Dataset`, this makes everything a lot easier.
You will first have to filter from the training and the validation dataset the positive and the negative examples and then take the 500.

I will do some considerations as follows, I will use the IMDB dataset from the `tfds` package. But you can apply the concept also to your example. I just don't exactly know how your dataset is built up. I am assuming it to be the same.

```
# import tensorflow_datasets package.
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds

# load the imdb dataset from the tfds, here you can have your own dataset as well.
dataset, info = tfds.load('imdb_reviews/plain_text', with_info=True, as_supervised=True, shuffle_files=True)

# Here the data is of type tuple and x is the imdb review whereas y is the label.
# 1 means positive and 0 means negative
updated_train_pos = dataset['train'].filter(lambda x,y: y == 1).take(500)
updated_train_neg = dataset['train'].filter(lambda x,y: y == 0).take(500)
train = updated_train_pos.concatenate(updated_train_neg)
# just reshuffle your dataset so that your batch might get positive as well as negative samples for training.
train = train.shuffle(1000, reshuffle_each_iteration=True)
```

Follow the same steps for getting your validation dataset ready.